# Forecast h2o.automl model in R

Tags: r, time-series, h2o

I have followed a tutorial for a first time go around with h2o in R from [here](https://rpubs.com/phamdinhkhanh/390053). What I would like to do is forecast the model on data I don't have, meaning beyond the test set, future dates.

The data is time series, and the predictions on the test set look like so:

```
print(automl.error.tbl)
# A time tibble: 10 x 5
# Index: Time
   Time       actual  pred   error error.pct
   <date>      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 2018-01-31  11.4  11.4   0.0342   0.00300
 2 2018-02-28  14.6  10.4   4.24     0.290  
 3 2018-03-31  12.2  11.4   0.762    0.0625 
 4 2018-04-30  15.0  10.8   4.20     0.281  
 5 2018-05-31  12.8  11.1   1.75     0.137  
 6 2018-06-30   8.67 10.8  -2.15    -0.248  
 7 2018-07-31  12.3  10.3   2.03     0.165  
 8 2018-08-31  13.5  10.4   3.17     0.234  
 9 2018-09-30  10.8   9.72  1.05     0.0976 
10 2018-10-31  10.5  10.7  -0.165   -0.0156
```

What I do not know how to do and am having difficulty finding is how to predict future data. For example with `fpp` I can do something like:

```
monthly.hw.fcast <- hw(
  monthly.rr.sub.xts
  , h = 12
  , alpha = monthly.fit.hw$alpha
)
```

And get what I am looking for, future predictions. Is there a simple way of doing that with an h20 model?

My code is as follows:

```
# h2o ####
library(h2o)
tk.monthly %>% glimpse()
tk.monthly.aug <- tk.monthly %>%
  tk_augment_timeseries_signature()
tk.monthly.aug %>% glimpse()

tk.monthly.tbl.clean <- tk.monthly.aug %>%
  select_if(~ !is.Date(.)) %>%
  select_if(~ !any(is.na(.))) %>%
  mutate_if(is.ordered, ~ as.character(.) %>% as.factor)

tk.monthly.tbl.clean %>% glimpse()

train.tbl <- tk.monthly.tbl.clean %>% filter(year < 2017)
valid.tbl <- tk.monthly.tbl.clean %>% filter(year == 2017)
test.tbl  <- tk.monthly.tbl.clean %>% filter(year == 2018)

h2o.init()

train.h2o <- as.h2o(train.tbl)
valid.h2o <- as.h2o(valid.tbl)
test.h2o <- as.h2o(test.tbl)

y <- "readmit.rate"
x <- setdiff(names(train.h2o), y)

automl.models.h2o <- h2o.automl(
  x = x
  , y = y
  , training_frame = train.h2o
  , validation_frame = valid.h2o
  , leaderboard_frame = test.h2o
  , max_runtime_secs = 60
  , stopping_metric = "deviance"
)

automl.leader <- automl.models.h2o@leader

pred.h2o <- h2o.predict(
  automl.leader
  , newdata = test.h2o
)

h2o.performance(
  automl.leader
  , newdata = test.h2o
)

# get mape
automl.error.tbl <- tk.monthly %>%
  filter(lubridate::year(Time) == 2018) %>%
  add_column(
    pred = pred.h2o %>%
      as.tibble() %>%
      pull(predict)
    ) %>%
  rename(actual = readmit.rate) %>%
  mutate(
    error = actual - pred
    , error.pct = error / actual
  )
print(automl.error.tbl)

automl.error.tbl %>%
  summarize(
    me = mean(error)
    , rmse = mean(error^2)^0.5
    , mae = mean(abs(error))
    , mape = mean(abs(error))
    , mpe = mean(error.pct)
  ) %>%
  glimpse()
```

Comment: I'd love to help, but this code is not reproducible.  I can't access the data and you need to import some other libraries as well to make this run-able code.  Also if you can clarify what your question is -- are you just asking how to predict on a test set?  That would be `predict(model, test)`.

Comment: I'm looking to predict on data i don't have. My code does `pred.h2o <- h2o.predict(automl.leader, newdata = test.h2o)` so I am already doing predictions on test data. For example in the FPP package one can simply do `hw(data.frame, h = number.of.periods.out)` and get predicted data in the future. h2o.predict on test.data is prediction on data you already have, so I know how good it works, I now want to predict say a month out on data I don't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data is not suited for standard supervised machine learning algorithms such as GBM, Random Forest, H2O AutoML, etc.  This is a forecasting problem using a single sequence of observations, where as "typical" supervised machine learning algorithms are meant to be used when you have several (or many) predictor columns, in addition to the column that you are trying to predict (the response).  I would take a look at other time-series/forecasting algorithms such as ARIMA or use a deep neural network such as an LSTM.

Comment: I ended up using ARIMA, ETS, HoltWinters etc.